# RLIB Multiple Agents with different training algorthims

Tags: reinforcement-learning, ray

In RLLIB is it possible to have multiple agents with different learning algorithms? (example: one agent using DQN and one agent using Q-Learning)?

Comment: See this MultiCartpole example which uses 2 trainers: [multi_agent_two_trainers.py](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/rllib/examples/multi_agent_two_trainers.py)

Comment: If the goal is (like it was in my case) two train with multiple algorithms in the SAME enviroment this https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/rllib/examples/two_trainer_workflow.py is what you are actually looking for. The two trainers in @Huan example are training on the same Enviroment but different insatnces of it as far as I could understand ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. See this example from the [documentation](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rllib-env.html):

> ```
> trainer = pg.PGAgent(env="my_multiagent_env", config={
> "multiagent": {
>     "policies": {
>         # the first tuple value is None -> uses default policy
>         "car1": (None, car_obs_space, car_act_space, {"gamma": 0.85}),
>         "car2": (None, car_obs_space, car_act_space, {"gamma": 0.99}),
>         "traffic_light": (None, tl_obs_space, tl_act_space, {}),
>     },
>     "policy_mapping_fn":
>         lambda agent_id:
>             "traffic_light"  # Traffic lights are always controlled by this policy
>             if agent_id.startswith("traffic_light_")
>             else random.choice(["car1", "car2"])  # Randomly choose from car policies
> }, })
>
>
>
> while True:
>      print(trainer.train())
> ```

in which each has a different PG algorithm.

Comment: I dont't think that this is the solution: You are just creating multuiple policies with the SAME Algorithm not different  ones ... https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/9278